# Conditional dozer xml mapping

Tags: java, dozer

In an object, i have two properties A and B. I want to map these properties based on condition to the target property T. I'm using xml based dozer mapping -

```
if(A != null)
  <field>
        <a>A</a>
        <b>T</b>
    </field>
else if (B != null)
   <field>
        <a>B</a>
        <b>T</b>
    </field>
```

How to achieve this in xml ?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is only possible with a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html "custom converter").

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are the only mapped properties and A and B can't be not null at the same time you can try to exclude mapping of null values:

```
<mapping map-null="false">
    <class-a>SrcClass</class-a>
    <class-b>DestClass</class-b>
    <field>
       <a>A</a>
       <b>T</b>
    </field>   
    <field>
       <a>B</a>
       <b>T</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

See also [Exclude Mapping Null Values](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html)